# How can I display an alertdialog in a dialog fragment in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I'm trying to display a custom alertdialog with a generated qr code in an imageView when the user clicks on a button on the parent dialog fragment. How can I do this?

Comment: `Alert Dialog` itself is a `Dialog`, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I have a custom dialog fragment with edittexts and spinners for taking user input, after that I want to show an alert dialog containing an imageView which will display a QR code for the transaction

Comment: You could refer to this link that create a dialog with image https://medium.com/@daRochaPires/custom-dialog-in-xamarin-android-8388e518b1d0